# Ошибка при создании Line Graph

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, graphics, d3.js

Постоянно выходит одна и та же ошибка

> Error: Invalid value for  attribute d="MNaN,
>   и так еще много много строк

вот мой код

```
<body>
<div class="container">

    <div class="jumbotron">

        <svg id="visualisation" width="1000" height="500"></svg>
    </div>
</div>
        <script>
            function getDate(d) {
                return new Date(d.RateDay);
            }
            function InitChart() {

                var data = @Html.Raw(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ViewBag.Data));
                data = JSON.parse(data);

                var parseDate = d3.time.format("%d%m%Y");
                data.forEach(function(d){

                    d.RateDay = parseDate(getDate(d)) ;

                });
                var dataGroup = d3.nest()
                    .key(function (d) {
                        return d.Currency;
                    }).entries(data);

            var vis = d3.select("#visualisation"),
                    WIDTH = 1000,
                    HEIGHT = 500,
                    MARGINS = {
                        top: 20,
                        right: 20,
                        bottom: 20,
                        left: 50
                    },
                    xScale = d3.scale.linear().range([MARGINS.left, WIDTH - MARGINS.right]).domain([d3.min(data, function(d) {
                        return d.year;
                    }), d3.max(data, function(d) {
                        return d.year;
                    })]),
                    yScale = d3.scale.linear().range([HEIGHT - MARGINS.top, MARGINS.bottom]).domain([d3.min(data, function(d) {
                        return d.sale;
                    }), d3.max(data, function(d) {
                        return d.sale;
                    })]),
                    xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                    .scale(xScale),
                    yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                    .scale(yScale)
                    .orient("left");
            vis.append("svg:g")
                .attr("class", "x axis")
                .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (HEIGHT - MARGINS.bottom) + ")")
                .call(xAxis);
            vis.append("svg:g")
                .attr("class", "y axis")
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + (MARGINS.left) + ",0)")
                .call(yAxis);
            var lineGen = d3.svg.line()
                .x(function(d) {
                    console.log(d.RateDay);
                    return xScale(d.RateDay);
                })
                .y(function(d) {
                    console.log(d.Value);
                    return yScale(d.Value);
                })
                .interpolate("basis");
            dataGroup.forEach(function(d, i) {
                vis.append('svg:path')
                    .attr('d', lineGen(d.values))
                    .attr('stroke', 'blue')
                    .attr('stroke-width', 2)
                    .attr('fill', 'none');
            });
            }
            InitChart();
        </script>
        </body>
```

Comment: У вас же тут `javascript`, а это `@Html.Raw(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ViewBag.Data));` откуда в нем? Или я чего-то не понимаю? О_о

Answer (score 1):

Судя по коду, вы правильно генерируете график. Хотя, конечно, есть вопросы по оптимальности. Уверен на 99%, что ошибка в формате данных. Может быть, вы неправильно получаете дату. Важно понимать, что `NaN` в js возвращается тогда, когда вы пытаетесь конвертировать не число в число, например, строку, в которой нет числовых символов - `parseInt('lol')`. Тут также - генератор `lineGen` при генерации пути обнаруживает непонятные данные и возвращает `NaN`. Для большего понимания графиков, я сделал пример простейшего графика на d3 [вот здесь](http://codepen.io/ReklatsMasters/pen/bdjvEQ).